# Creating index on schema binding view in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, indexing, view

I am trying to create index for schema binding view. This view contains union all operator and some joins also. How can I create an index for this view? Because I am using the type of views in my procedure using left join. So I have to improve performance.

For example

```
create table a
(
     prodid int,
     prodname varchar(100)
)

insert into a values(1,'ramesh')

create table b
(
     prodid int,
     prodname varchar(100)
)

insert into b values(2,'kumar')

create view v1 
with schemabinding 
as
     select tb1.prodid, tb1.prodname 
     from dbo.a tb1 
     union all 
     select tb2.prodid, tb2.prodname 
     from dbo.b tb2
```

View is created successfully, but I'm not able to create index for the above view - I get an error

> it contains one or more union,intersect operators

So any other method to create index for this view?

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX  CX_V1
ON dbo.v1(prodid, prodname);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with `SCHEMABINDING` but because `UNION ALL` is not allowed in an index view. I would expect the error message to be clear about that. See [the documentation for index view requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/create-indexed-views).

Also, why index this view? I wouldn't expect the indexed view will improve performance significantly, assuming the underlying tables have a unique nonclustered index on `prodid` and `prodname`.

Comment: ok. i am using five left joins with five views.it contains more records.so i tried to create index on views to improve performance.Shall i create five temp tables and store the results of views and create index on the temp tables in my stored procedure?.is it improve performance?

Comment: @Ram, this is an entirely different question than the one you asked. I would start with query and index tuning of the query with the 5 left joins. If performance isn't acceptable, using temp tables may or may not be the way the best approach. If you need help with that, ask another question, including the CREATE table and DDL, along with the query.

Comment: Thank you.i will ask another question with query.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create an index on a view that makes use of a union operator, and i dont think there's any way.

Comment: Thank you.i will try with temp table and index on temp table.